# Representing a nested stacked bar chart

Tags: bar-chart, business-intelligence, qlikview

I'm a QlikView beginner and I'm working with a piece of data; trying to visualize it as a bar chart.

More specifically, I need to develop a nested stacked bar chart as shown in the image. 
At a top level, for every project, I need to have the length of the stacks of the bar chart proportional to "TotalUpdates" for the 5 different project locations. (Loc 1 to Loc 5)

At a second level, within each one of the stacks that I described above, I need to be able to represent the percentage of completion. Which is UpdatesCompleted/TotalUpdates. (Shaded or colored differently)

I tried using the crosstable, but it did not work. Since I'm trying to work with three dimensions, I'm unable to find a suitable solution to handle this. 
A snapshot of the input spreadsheet and the desired representation is attached. 
[image: input spreadsheet]
[image: Desired bar chart]

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement is challenging and I have not the perfect solution for you but two approaches.

The first one is a simple chart with two the dimensions *ProjectType* and *ProjectSource*.

[image: simple solution]

The advantage of this chart is that it is simple and scales with increasing projects and locations. There are only two formulas:

```
Updates: = sum(UpdatesCompleted)
Total:   = sum(TotalUpdates)
```

But because of the stacking of the values I changed it to:

```
Total:   = sum(TotalUpdates)-sum(UpdatesCompleted)
```

The second one comes closer to your requirement:

[image: solution with set analysis]

But it uses **set analysis** (see page 799 in the Reference PDF) to define the values of the colums and you have to add a new coloumn when your data contains a new location.

[image]

The description for the first column (*Loc 1*) is:

```
='Loc 1  ' & Round(sum({1<ProjectSource={'Loc 1'}>}TotalUpdates)*100/sum(TotalUpdates)) & '%'
```

And the definition is:

```
=sum({1<ProjectSource={'Loc 1'} >}UpdatesCompleted)/sum({1<ProjectSource={'Loc 1'} >}TotalUpdates)
```

Additionaly I set the backgroundcolurs for the first three columns

[image]

to visualise the progress (<0.5 red; orange; >0.8 green)

Hope that helps.